# setCookie() function is not working when $_SERVER["http_referer"] is not received in php

Tags: php

I am trying to set cookie using setCookie function in php. For the first time when I start browser, it is not working. When I reload page, I am receiving cookies from server. This proves that setCookie() function is not working when $_SERVER["http_referer"] is not received. Is there any setting in php.ini file to solve this issue?

Comment: when you first go to the server your just sending the cookie,

Comment: I am not sending any cookie to server. For the first time I am not receiving any cookie. When I reload page, I am receiving cookies from server. When I am navigating through pages, I am receiving cookies. But for first time when I come to website I am not receiving any cookies.

Comment: what do u meant to say with your comment ?

Comment: You have no real idea how cookies work, correct?

Comment: I know what are cookies and how it works very well. But above scenario is happening in one of my sites. Is there any setting in php.ini file to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your conclusion is wrong. You can prove that by configuring your browser so it *never* sends the `Referer` HTTP header.

From the [setcookie() manual page](http://php.net/setcookie):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed **on the next page
>   load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

In plain English, this means that `$_COOKIE` contains the cookies *received* by the page, not the ones *sent*.

---

**Edit:** You can't make PHP append outgoing cookies to `$_COOKIE` automatically but nothing prevents you from doing it yourself—superglobals are not read-only:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
$_COOKIE["TestCookie"] = $value;
```

Comment: +1 :) for the answer :D

Comment: I know that my conclusion is wrong but above scenario is happening in one of my sites. Is there any setting in php.ini file to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes.. cookies become active after a page refresh. It does not matter if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is set:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays. Note, superglobals such as $_COOKIE became available in PHP 4.1.0. Cookie values also exist in $_REQUEST.

[See Documentation here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on the usage of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

$_COOKIE is populated before your PHP script is executed (with whatever cookies the user already has). When you call `setcookie()` it does not update the $_COOKIE global variable automatically. However, on the next page load it will populate correctly.

When the user requests a page from the server, it sends all the cookies it has for that domain to the server. The server will then use it to populate the $_COOKIE global variables and then executes your script.

When you call the `setcookie()` function, that adds a header to your response back to the client (which is only sent after the entire page is finished executing) telling it to store this new cookie. So when the next time the user requests a page, it will send this new cookie on to you.

To "fix" this in your code, you can do this:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie']))
{
    setcookie('my_cookie', 'value');
    $_COOKIE['my_cookie'] = 'value';
}

// do logic with $_COOKIE here
if (isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie']) && $_COOKIE['my_cookie'] = 'x')
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: It is populated at the script execution (how is it triggered if the code is not executed). The cookie is available cuz of the response from server on the second browser request. Or at least that is what I know. Sorry if I am wrong here :)